# Trying to install CUDA on Ubuntu 13.10 Amazon g2.2xlarge GPU Cluster

Tags: installation, 13.10, dependencies, cuda

Does anybody know a way to do this? I have tried the following from...

http://vasir.net/blog/opencl/installing-cuda-opencl-pyopencl-on-aws-ec2

http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/saucy/multiverse/n/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/install.html

But it seems hopeless, because every time it ends up in some kind of package dependency error like this...

```
ubuntu@ip-10-33-136-37:~$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-profiler (= 5.0.35-7ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 5.0.35-7ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: nvidia-visual-profiler (= 5.0.35-7ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
```

Any help would be appreciated, this is driving me up the wall.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-profiler nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-visual-profiler
```

This should install it and the unmet dependencies. If this does not work, these packages may not exist in these versions in your Ubuntu installation. Maybe you should try enabling multiverse?